# Raspberry Pi 2 - Model B - no boot with Raspbmc

Tags: boot, raspbmc, led

I was trying my brand new Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

I've used the Raspbmc installer to "burn" the image on my micro sd.

After I've connected the raspberry to the ac adapter and then to the TV, nothing happened.

Only the "multicolors" image appeared on the TV. Nothing else.

Only the red led turned on. The green led turns on only when I remove the SD card.

I've tried 2 different kind of SD card, but nothinf changed.

Comment: Remove power from the Pi.  Insert the SD card.  Apply power to the Pi.  What do the red and green LEDs do?

Answer (score 2):

i remember, when the raspberry was announced they say at the moment only raspbian and ubuntu are running on the PI2. You should use the successor of Raspbmc: OSMC. this works perfect on the new Pi2

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the img to the sdcard again, or try one of the other kodi distributions.

(OpenELEC, OSMC, XBian, Raspbian + XBMC)

Raspbmc is discontinued, and sometimes one of the distributions breaks so it's nice to have alternatives.